# How to display record information from my Firebase database?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have in my database this node :

[image]

I have this  select list

[image]

I would search events that its startdate matches the select item from the select list.

I try this code to show the evets that matches 'today' startdate:

```
//Switch label of selected item : 
 switch($scope.search.dateOption.label)
 {
  case 'Today':
   {
    var reff = new Firebase("https://event-application.firebaseio.com/event");
    reff.orderByChild("startdate").startAt((new Date()).toISOString())
    .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.key())
    var a= snapshot.key() ; 
   reff.orderByChild("id").equalTo(a).on("child_added", function(snapshot)  { 
  console.log(snapshot);
  });
 })
   }
    break;
 }
```

'console.log(snapshot.key())' works well :

[image]

But when i try to display all the record information, nothing is displayed.
Can someone help me please.

Comment: This is dependent upon how you are trying to display it. Include that code as well.

Comment: For the moment, i would to display it in console.

Comment: You mean `console.log(snapshot.val())`?

Comment: yees. I tried it but nothing is displayed

Comment: My  problem is that i don"t find the best way to  define the id of the event in  `orderByChild("id")`